Theorem 2.49 in Folland; is it a pushforward measure?
This is a follow-up question to this question. Consider Theorem 2.49 in Folland's real analysis text:

We denote $S^{n-1}$ the unit sphere $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|x|=1\}$. If $x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$, the polar coordinates of $x$ are
$$r=|x| \in (0,\infty),\quad x'=x/|x| \in S^{n-1}$$
The map $\Phi(x)=(r,x')$ is a continuous bijection from $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ to $(0,\infty)\times S^{n-1}$ whose continuous inverse is $\Phi^{-1}(r,x')=rx'$. We denote by $m_*$ the Borel measure on $(0,\infty)\times S^{n-1}$ induced by $\Phi$ from Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is, $m_*(E)=m(\Phi^{-1}(E))$. We define the measure $\rho=\rho_n$ on $(0,\infty)$ by $\rho(E) = \int_E r^{n-1} dr$.
2.49 Theorem There is a unique Borel measure $\sigma= \sigma_{n-1}$ on $S^{n-1}$ such that $m_*= \rho \times \sigma$. If $f$ is Borel measurable on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f \ge 0 $ or $f \in L^1(m)$, then
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) \,dx = \int_0^\infty \int_{S^{n-1}} f(rx') r^{n-1} \,d\sigma (x') dr.\tag{2.50}$$

My question concerns the following part of the proof:

If $E$ is a Borel set in $S^{n-1}$, for $a > 0$ let
$$
E_a = \Phi^{-1}((0,a] \times E) = \{rx' : 0 < r \leq a, \, x' \in E\}.
$$
If $(2.50)$ is to hold when $f = \chi_{E_1}$, we must have
$$
m(E_1) = \int_0^1 \int_E r^{n-1} d\sigma(x') \, dr = \sigma(E) \int_0^1 r^{n-1} \, dr = \frac{\sigma(E)}{n}.
$$
We therefore define $\sigma(E)$ to be $n \cdot m(E_1)$. Since the map $E \mapsto E_1$ takes Borel sets to Borel sets and commutes with unions, intersections, and complements, it is clear that $\sigma$ is a Borel measure on $S^{n-1}$.

I wonder;

What relevance does the fact have that the map $E\mapsto E_1$ commutes with intersections and complements? To verify $\sigma$ is a measure, I think we only require that it commutes with unions.
Is $\sigma$ a pushforward measure? If yes, what is the measurable function which pushes $m$ forward?

Here's my attempt at answering 2. We have $\Phi(x)=(r,x')$, where $r=|x|\in(0,\infty)$ and $x'=x/|x|\in S^{n-1}$, and it is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}\to (0,\infty)\times S^{n-1}$ with inverse $\Phi^{-1}$ given by $(r,x')\mapsto rx'$. Recall also $E_1=\Phi^{-1}((0,1]\times E)$. If we restrict $\Phi$ to the closed unit ball minus its center, which we denote $B$, then we obtain the map $\Psi:B\to (0,1]\times S^{n-1}$. Still I think $E_1=\Psi^{-1}((0,1]\times E)$ and recall one can define the $x$- and $y$-section of a multivariable function. Similarly, we can define the $r$-section of $\Psi^{-1}$ to be $\Psi^{-1}_r(x')=\Psi^{-1}(r,x')=rx'$. Using the identity $(f_x)^{-1}(C)=(f^{-1}(C))_x$, we have $$\big(\Psi_r^{-1}\big)^{-1}(E_1)=\big((\Psi^{-1})^{-1}(E_1))_r=\big(\Psi(E_1))_r=\{x':(r,x')\in \Psi(E_1)\}=E,$$since $\Psi(E_1)=(0,1]\times E$. So, is $\sigma$ the pushforward of $m$ under the inverse of $\Psi_r^{-1}$? I'm not sure this is correct, and if so, what the inverse of $\Psi_r^{-1}$ is.
